# export problem in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, export

when i try to export my data from system>import/export>export 
when i select the product option and press on continue its start processing and after 120 sec it's show a error page that 500-internal server error 
when i contact to my hosting provider they told me that its not there side error anyone can help me according this issue.it is a timeout problem but it start suddenly can anyone help me according to this problem that how to solve it.
advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to fix 500 internal server error in Magento.

**Change Magento file permission**

1. Go to file manager of your Magento website
2. Change permission of index.php file in root from 664 to 644.

**Increase "php_value memory_limit"**

Add the following lines in .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 256M
</IfModule>
```

**Rename/remove .htaccess file**

Sometimes, renaming/removing .htaccess file can fix 500 internal server error, as it removes wrong url rewrite/redirect setting.

You can also try disabling Magento maintenance mode and installing CURL extension. You can find more information about these methods [here](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-http-error-500/).

Answer (score 0):

Problem with:

> app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php

You can rewrite file and change

````
                foreach ($productData as $storeId => &$dataRow) {
                    if ($defaultStoreId != $storeId) {
                        $dataRow[self::COL_SKU]      = null;
                        $dataRow[self::COL_ATTR_SET] = null;
                        $dataRow[self::COL_TYPE]     = null;
                    } else {
                        $dataRow[self::COL_STORE] = null;
                        $dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
                    }``` ->  ``` foreach ($dataRows as $productId => &$productData) {
                foreach ($productData as $storeId => &$dataRow) {
                    if ($defaultStoreId != $storeId) {
                        $dataRow[self::COL_SKU]      = null;
                        $dataRow[self::COL_ATTR_SET] = null;
                        $dataRow[self::COL_TYPE]     = null;
                    } else {
                        $dataRow[self::COL_STORE] = null;
                        if (isset($stockItemRows[$productId])) {
                            $dataRow = array_merge($dataRow, $stockItemRows[$productId]);
                        }
                    }
````